# How do I get from Tisno to Zadar airport for a 6 AM flight?

Tags: airport-transfer, croatia, festivals, zad

I have a 6am flight on Ryanair on a Wednesday from Zadar airport. I need to figure out how to get from my festival site in Tisno (Croatia) to Zadar airport in a reasonable amount of time. How do I make it without spending 100 euros?

Comment: 1. What exact time should you be at the airport? 40 mins before 6.00am? 2. Is it fine if it costs 95 euros? Be more precise, what is your budget and amount of time? would spending the night at the airport be fine?

Comment: Check in closes an hour before. Is there no bus transfer? my budget is about 50 euros

Comment: The festival ends about 2am so I can leave right after.

Comment: Ask around to see if anyone else is making the same journey, and share the ride with them?

Comment: Have I understood your situation correctly? You can't leave Tisno before 2AM, you have to be at Zadar Airport well before the checkin closes at 5AM, you won't spend more than 50€ and you expect to find a suitable bus connection in rural Croatia in the middle of the night?

Comment: hey this is my first time to croatia.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that you'll able to do it by bus.  The night buses are seasonal only, and the only source of info I can find for night time buses is [BusCroatia](http://www.buscroatia.com).

They indicate that you'd likely have to go by taxi from Tisno to either Vodice or Pirovac, and then catch the route from Vodice to Zadar that passes through Pirovac.

You want to check in an hour before, meaning you need to be at the airport at 5 at the latest, and it'll take 30 min from Zadar town (conservative estimate).  So you want to arrive by 4.30am at the latest.

You say the festival ends at 2, so that's a fairly narrow window, given the bus takes 1 hour and 1 minutes to go from Vodice to Zadar.

[The list of night routes that I can find](http://www.buscroatia.com/routes-search/?dS=Vodice&aS=zadar&d&t) indicates that there are buses leaving Vodice at 1.16am, and 6.50am.  Obviously the latter is too late, meaning if you really want to take a bus, you're going to want to leave the festival in a taxi to get TO Vodice ([14.5km or 16 minutes by car](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Tisno,%20Croatia&daddr=Vodice,%20Croatia&hl=en&sll=-37.860283,145.079616&sspn=1.719597,3.56781&geocode=FdpLnAId_a3uACntdjXfWdA0EzH5V4sWgBj2Yg;Fdi9mwIdyMPwACnRFIxP8Nc0EzFUqsVHHNpWQA&oq=vodi&mra=ls&t=m&z=13)) before 1am, to ensure you catch the bus on time.

So realistically, you have the following options :

- pay up for a taxi for yourself to Zadar airport
- find others to share a taxi with
- miss the last hour of the festival and hope your connections (Taxi, bus, taxi) all work out
- wing it, and hope that when you're in Tisno you'll find a special bus or shuttle that's being put on just for the festival (it happens sometimes!) and therefore won't be online.
- change your flight to the next day, removing all stress from this.

enjoy it!